# Using Modernizr to Trigger Script

Tags: modernizr

I am attempting to learn Modernizr (or how to use it I should say) and seem to be stuck.

I want to fire a script if the browser does *not* support CSS3 Animations

I have modernizr set to check for css animations and I have this script (at the bottom of the page):

```
if (Modernizr.cssanimations) {
    //Script to Run
}
```

When I open Firefox (which supports CSS3 Animations) the script fires. When I open IE (which does not support CSS3 Animations) the script does not fire.

What do I have wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modernizr's flags tell you whether the feature is *supported.* So your `if` statement is saying "if CSS animations are supported, then do stuff." That's exactly the opposite of what you said you wanted -- you want to do stuff if CSS animations are *not* supported.

Do this instead:

```
if (!Modernizr.cssanimations) {
    //Script to Run
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you should either use a ! before Modernizr.cssanimations
or use an else statement.